# can't iterate over backbone collection, could be a fetch/bind issue

Tags: backbone.js, handlebars.js, backbone.js-collections

I'm grabbing a list of a users friends, into a collection, and I want to iterate over those friends so that the user can select a friend and do a bunch of stuff later.

in my initalize I've got

```
friends = new MyApp.Collections.UserFriends();
friends.fetch({ data: $.param({ search: this.model.attributes.user_id}),
            success: function(){

            },
            error: function(){
                alert('error getting friends');
            }
         });


         friends.bind('fetched', this.render(),this);
```

Then in my render I have

```
console.log(friends);
    console.log(HandlebarsTemplates['friends/friendsResults'](friends);
    $(this.el).html(HandlebarsTemplates['friends/friendsResults'](friends);
```

my handlebars is

```
ok, I have the right handlebar template
{{#each models}}
<li>   {{attributes.username}}</li>
{{/each}}
```

the friends collection in the console is, so I can see that the models are there.

```
byCid: Object
_byId: Object
_callbacks: Object
length: 39
models: Array[39]
__proto__: q
```

my concern was that the problem was that render was being triggered before the collection was made, but that is what I thought the `friends.bind('fetched',this.render(), this)` was supposed to resolve.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no 'fetched' event in Backbone, try to use 'reset', http://backbonejs.org/#FAQ-events.

Comment: thanks Yaroslav, I tried `reset`, but still nothing showing up in the handlebar template. I was sure I had been told to use 'fetched' before.

Comment: And remove brackets `friends.bind('fetched',this.render/*()*/, this)` (this javascript...)